# ASP.NET DropDownList OnSelectedIndexChanged event not fired

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, postback

I'm trying to use some AJAX and ASP.Net together to enable me to run functions without having to refresh the whole page but i've stumbled across a problem in doing this

Here's my code

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="update1" />

        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And here's my code behind

```
 Sub update1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

    txt1.Text = Now.ToString

End Sub
```

The event doesn't fire because I don't have `AutoPostBack="True"` on my ddl but adding that to the ddl will postback the whole page.

Is there a way to avoid using `AutoPostBack="True"` so that it only updates the panel?

I know I can use an `asp:Button` to get around this but i'd really like to be able to use a ddl with `OnSelectedIndexChanged`

Thanks

Comment: r u sure AutoPostBack="True" postback whole page?

Comment: Adding autopostback='true' should not postback the entire page (at least the page won't flickr) - it should just update the contents of the update panel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to avoid to send the whole viewstate to the server, you should look at [callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Instead, if you want to avoid a refresh of the entire page, but with postback, this should work:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="update1" AutoPostBack="True"  />

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
         <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="ddl1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: AutoPostBack="True".  Thanks.  I hate using UpdatePanels (I prefer JQuery) so I feel like I'm going back in time.  But this is what I needed today. Upvote.

Comment: Why this answer isn't given everywhere else with a similar question has been asked is completely beyond me.  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new page with same codes and different page name. Worked for me

Comment: please comment it or improve it